# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - How to deal with Zend standard model

Tags: php, database, model, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I integrated `Doctrine 2` into my `Zend` project. If you use `Doctrine` you put your data definition in `Entity\MyEntity.php` and not (like it's shown in the [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)) into `Model\MyModel.php`.

The tutorial uses the *MyModelTable.php* as a Manager where you can define queries like `fetchAll()` etc.

How do I archive this with Doctrine? And can I just delete my `model` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [DoctrineORMModule](http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)? This integrates Doctrine properly into ZF as a service. Once you've done this, for each of your own modules that include Doctrine entities, add this to your module.config.php:

```
<?php

namespace YourModul;

return array(
    // ... your module configuration ...

    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
                ),
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

This configures Doctrine to look for Annotation-configured Entities in `modules/YourModule/src/YourModule/Entity/`, using the default DBAL driver.

You'll also need to configure Doctrine's DBAL component as described on the [DoctrineORMModule page](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#readme).

To cleanup, you can simply delete your model directory and use the Entity classes you define. Everything else works as usual.